# Query syntax error

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I tried a lot but can't find what is wrong with this query, It gave me this error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
         SELECT  * 
         FROM     ( 
                           SELECT   *, 
                                    Row_number() OVER (partition BY sequenceno ORDER BY sequenceno DESC) AS rn
                           FROM     wirelistnew)w 
         ORDER BY w.t1_installation ASC, 
                  w.t1_location ASC, 
                  w.t1_devmountloc ASC, 
                  w.t2_devmountloc ASC, 
                  w.t1_devicetag_anum ASC, 
                  w.t1_cp_anum, 
                  CASE w.t1_symboltype 
                           WHEN 'terminal' THEN CONVERT (INT, Substring(w.t1_devicetag, Patindex('%[:]%', w.t1_devicetag)+1, (Len(w.t1_devicetag))-(Patindex('%[:]%', w.t1_devicetag))))) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` expression doesn't have the `END`

```
CASE W.T1_SymbolType 
            WHEN  'terminal' THEN convert (int, SUBSTRING(W.T1_DeviceTag, PATINDEX('%[:]%', W.T1_DeviceTag)+1, (LEN(W.T1_DeviceTag))-(PATINDEX('%[:]%', W.T1_DeviceTag))))
            END
)
```

Your next problem will be that the `ORDER BY` is invalid because it is not at the top level (or part of a `TOP`, `OFFSET`, or `FOR XML` clause).

Comment: Thanks so how to change this code ,i do cte cause i want remove the duplicate values